# Chromatic aberration in white light

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses, wavelength

After noticing that red lights (e.g., in neon signs) look really sharp while blue ones look blurry, I searched for the cause of this effect. Apparently it's due to [chromatic aberration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration). In a nutshell, the refraction index of the lens is dependent on the wavelength of the light. This results in the failure of focusing all colors on the same convergence point.

[image]

What I don't completely understand is the following. If white light is a mix of all colors, why don't we see a blur/glow that becomes bluer - and dimmer - the further it is from the light source? Why do white neon signs, for example, have a completely white blur around them when looked from a distance?

Comment: Are you talking about "as seen by the human eye"? Lots of research shows that our brains filter, invent, and distort what we see--especially the colors we perceive.

Comment: I don't think that chromatic aberration is the major reason why red neon signs are blurry. Especially since they are approximately monochromatic.